Installing epson scanner in Kubuntu and non free plugin
I downloaded the Epson scanner drivers from https://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php
When I run the help option:
./install.sh --help
'install.sh'

Usage: ./install.sh --help
       ./install.sh {--dry-run} [--with-non-free-plugin|--without-non-free-plugin]

The following options are supported:

  -h, --help                    display this message and exit
  --dry-run                     show what would be installed without actually
                                doing so
  --with-non-free-plugin        install the non-free plugin
                                This is the default behavior.
  --without-non-free-plugin     do not install the non-free plugin

What is that non-free-plugin which is mentioned as the default behaviour? Do I need it? Does it require some payment to use?

Why the downvote?

The Epson Scan 2 Manual
has this information in section
5.1.2. Installation in command:

Installing plug-in package (When network scanning or optional image processing function is required)

Some more information is found in this
description
of a port for this plugin:

This port provides the Linux binaries needed to access the scanner over the network and for some older USB models.

The plugin seems to be free, as its source is freely available
for download.
I just remark that in three Linux distributions I have looked at,
there was nothing said about the "non-free plugin" being payware.
I suppose it's actually free-to-use in spite of its name.
Some software is the property of some private body and not released
to the public domain, but it stays free-to-use for as long
as is authorized by the copyright holder.

one can never know without trying so if a plugin is not free in linux what happens then? Do we get some error message with e.g. a URL to paypal to pay for example?

That depends on the plugin. Basically, if nothing happens then this plugin is now free and its name is historical in nature. Many proprietary software has become public domain after some time has passed. I haven't found any documentation about paying for this "non-free" plugin.

To the downvoters: I suppose this is because of the sentence "one can never know without trying", so I replaced it. I remark that in computers one can always have surprises, so some uncertainty factor always exists.
